# What does a backslash represent when searching for decimals

Tags: grep, regular-expression, quoting

I want to understand what the backslash represents in this command. `grep "\.900983" table`

I know what the command does, it searches for the `900983` value in `table`, I'm just not sure of the purpose of the \ or what it does.

Comment: Okay you gave me an idea, could it be that it cancels out the digits before the decimal point, and only searches for whatever is after the decimal point?

Comment: No. Without the backslash, the period will match **any single character.** *With* the backslash, the period will **only** match a **period.** You say in your question that the command "searches for the `900983` value." That's not exactly correct; it searches for the decimal fraction `.900983` (note the leading decimal.)

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax thanks for the explanation, I understand it now.

Comment: Glad to help. If you need (or want) to learn more about regular expressions, I recommend O'reilly's *Mastering Regular Expressions* by Jeremy Freidl. It's quite comprehensive, so I suggest borrowing a copy first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.` is a regular expression [*metacharacter*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_03) which matches *any single character*.

`\` is also a regular expression *metacharacter* which can be used to *escape* any *metacharacter* so that it will be *literally* matched.

and so `.` matches any character, but `\.` matches only `.`.

```sh
printf %c900983\\n a . | grep -n ".900983"
```

---

```
1:a900983
2:.900983
```

...because the `.` regular expression *metacharacter* matches a literal `.` *or* an `a` or *any other single character*, but...

```sh
printf %c900983\\n a . | grep -n "\.900983"
```

---

```
2:.900983
```